# These clothes were expected ____ by people under twenty only

Tags: tense, passive-voice, infinitives

> "These clothes were expected _______ by people under twenty only."
>
> a) to wear
>   b) to be wearing
>   c) to be worn
>   d) to have worn

It sounds like somebody already wore the clothes.  So because of this can we say option d is right? or it is always b

Comment: c) to be worn. You wouldn't want to see me wearing a onesie - nor [Louis Walsh](http://www.thebrag.tv/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Louis+onesie.jpg) Such things were meant to be worn by people under twenty

Comment: :) what about if I say  "Such things are meant to be worn by people under twenty"  Does it not make a sense?

Comment: You'd need a better grammarian to say exactly why, but yes, still works with present tense 'are meant'. I'm guessing it's because 'to be worn' comes out as an infinitive - but I'd wait for a proper grammarian, to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

"to be worn" is the only correct answer.

Comment: Thank you. Because you said " the only " , is there any situation where we can use " to have worn by "

Comment: no, unless you insert "been" and change the context a little: "That crown was the first to have been worn by a British monarch."

Comment: I should say I am a bit confused because my example sentence and your example sentence seem to be the same for me..If I analyze your sentence does it mean " the crown  was worn in the past" So we use past tense of be and it still has been worn so if I say  " the crown is the first to have been worn by the monarch " Does mean it that there is only one crown ? and second question if I say " "That crown was the first to be worn by a British monarch."   Does it mean  "the monarch no longer wore the crown"?

Comment: The difference is that you had "to have worn by" without "been." "Been" is necessary here because it's a passive construction.

Comment: You can say "the first to be worn" or "the first to have been worn" and they both basically mean the same thing. The form with the passive is a little more vivid and "dramatic," making the statement a bit more epic.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects which can be confusing:

1.Voice. From the given answers a), b) and d) are active, and only c) is passive. That is why it is the right answer. If you choose one of the others, it means that the clothes have to wear the people, which obviously doesn't make sense. Here is an example sentence where these 3 could be correct:

> Only people under twenty were expected *to wear/to have worn/to be wearing* these clothes.

2.Time. "Are/were expected to", "are/were meant to", "are/were supposed to" don't change what follows. What follows is an infinitive, and the possible answers reflect that. Whether the expectations are in the present or in the past, the infinitive construction stays the same.

What can happen to this infinitive is, we can have a simple infinitive ("were expected to be worn"), or a perfect one ("were expected to have been worn"). In the first case these people might still wear the clothes, and in the second, it is a thing of the past, for example for a particular occasion:

> These clothes were expected to be worn on formal occasions, not for parties. (This means we expected people to wear them on formal occasions, whether in the past or now.)
>
> The clothes they were given were expected to have been worn during the reception last night, not during the conference.